# Python Sqlalchemy insert data into AWS Redshift

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I want to load a large excel table data into AWS Redshift, using Python psycopg2 take a long time to load, so I try to use Sqlalchemy. but the **redshift-sqlalchemy** documentation is confusing. So I want to use the regular Sqlalchemy library. Below code can pull data from AWS redshift, I don't know how to modify it to INSERT data into redshift. if possible, I like to INSERT data at once.

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import text

sql = """
SELECT top 10 * FROM pg_user;
""" 

redshift_endpoint1 = "YourDBname.cksrxes2iuiu.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com"
redshift_user1 = "YourUserName"
redshift_pass1 = "YourRedshiftPassword"
port1 = 8192 #whaterver your Redshift portnumber is
dbname1 = "YourDBname"

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import text
engine_string = "postgresql+psycopg2://%s:%s@%s:%d/%s" \
% (redshift_user1, redshift_pass1, redshift_endpoint1, port1, dbname1)
engine1 = create_engine(engine_string)

df1 = pd.read_sql_query(text(sql), engine1)
```

Comment: You can use pandas `to_sql` method (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

Comment: @MP24 what should I put for the con  DataFrame.to_sql(name, con)   ?  a sqlalchemy.engine or Connection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'id':['444'],'id2':[555]})

df.to_sql('YourTable', con=engine1,if_exists='append',index= False)